# How to limit data that mongodb return according to parents slug for each result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've a very big collection in mongo data has to much data,and each document has got a reference of it parent by a kind of one to many relashionship.The parent collection is category and the Child collection for example Products.And for each products there a parents_slug.How can i query the Product collection so that in the result i return for each parent only only 10 documents.So limting children result to 10 for each parent.

Here is an example :

```
[
    {
        "prioritization": {
            "enum": []
        },
        "_id": "5d41d1034b2b8e49347f1759",
        "_parent_slug":"abc"
        "year": 2019,
        "name": "Kana 2019",
        "revision": 1,
        "slug": "kana-2019",
        "__v": 0
    },
      {
        "prioritization": {
            "enum": []
        },
        "_id": "5d41d1034b2b8e49347f1759",
        "_parent_slug":"cde"
        "year": 2019,
        "name": "Kana 2019",
        "revision": 1,
        "slug": "kana-2019",
        "__v": 0
    },
      {
        "prioritization": {
            "enum": []
        },
        "_id": "5d41d1034b2b8e49347f1759",
        "_parent_slug":"efg"
        "year": 2019,
        "name": "Kana 2019",
        "revision": 1,
        "slug": "kana-2019",
        "__v": 0
    },
      {
        "prioritization": {
            "enum": []
        },
        "_id": "5d41d1034b2b8e49347f1759",
        "_parent_slug":"abc"
        "year": 2019,
        "name": "Kana 2019",
        "revision": 1,
        "slug": "kana-2019",
        "__v": 0
    },
      {
        "prioritization": {
            "enum": []
        },
        "_id": "5d41d1034b2b8e49347f1759",
        "_parent_slug":"cde"
        "year": 2019,
        "name": "Kana 2019",
        "revision": 1,
        "slug": "kana-2019",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

In this above collection we have `abc`,`cde` as `parent_slugs`.So instead of fetching all the collection,i want for abc,only `10 children`,for `cde` 10 children also.I can only limit the number of result by collection using `Children.find().limit(myLimit);` and it doesn't give me what i really need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below queries

```
Children.find("_parent_slug" : "abc").limit(myLimit)

Children.find("_parent_slug" : "cde").limit(myLimit)
```